# Youtube and Google maps iframe makes invisible in Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have problem with embeding youtube and google maps iframes on my website. The problem appears in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Opera). I have a jQuery script which resizes iframe to fit browser width (to keep responsiveness on different devices) and after that iframe becomes invisible.

The problem appears in a such use case:

1. Make small browser window width (or use mobile phone)
2. Refresh page
3. iframe is visible but not fits window width
4. Javascript is running and changes iframe width and height to fit the window width
5. iframe becomes invisible
6. If I manually change window size, iframe becomes visible again (only on desktop, on mobile phones iframe is always invisible, there is no way to change window size)

The problem is only while embedding youtube and Google maps, other iframes works perfect.

This is URL with such problem: https://www.rtu.lv/lv/nac-studet

Simlified code example:

```
$(window).resize (function (){     
    $('iframe, img').each (function () {   
        if (!empty ($(this).attr('data-default-width'))) {      
            var w = $(this).closest('div').actual('width');
            var m = parseFloat ($(this).attr('data-margins'));   
            var dw = parseFloat ($(this).attr('data-default-width'));
            var dh = parseFloat ($(this).attr('data-default-height'));
            var ar = parseFloat ($(this).attr('data-aspect-ratio'));                                  
            if (dw+m>w) {
                if ($(this).width()!=w-m) {
                    $(this).width(w-m);
                    $(this).height((w-m)/ar);    
                    if (($(this).is('iframe')) && ($(this).css('float')=='left')) {
                        //IF CHROME, IFRAME IS INVISIBLE. WHAT IS NEXT???
                    }                                                                                        
                }
            } else if (dw+m<=w) {
                if ($(this).width()!=dw) {  
                    $(this).width(dw);     
                    $(this).height(dh);  
                    if (($(this).is('iframe')) && ($(this).css('float')=='left')) {
                        //IF CHROME, IFRAME IS INVISIBLE. WHAT IS NEXT???    
                    }                                                                                          
                }   
            }                          
        }                                   
    })   
})
```

Comment: Here are some screens:
1) just after refresh https://unibit.lv/other/rtu/chrome.png
2) after manual window size change https://unibit.lv/other/rtu/chrome2.png

Comment: I noticed that there is no problem if I don't use "float: left" iframe style attribute or don't place <div> with style "clear: both" after content.

Comment: https://youtu.be/UrHjTuOtmhE - video example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
$('iframe').css('transform', 'scale(0.9999)');    
$('iframe').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
```